# How to run a single E2E test with Testacular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

[Testacular](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular/) is really nice test runner and I like it very much. Running my unit test I noticed that the test is run is the test that the cursor is on but, that is not the case with  E2E tests. Running all e2e test to verify a single test is really tedious and time waste. Does anybody know how to run a single e2e test. Is there some configs that I miss that can make me run a single e2e test ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can change `describe()` and `it()` to `xdescribe()` and `xit()` accordingly to skip certain stories and scenarios.

Comment: you mean to comment them ? or something like that ?

Comment: This is a way to skip their running. Once test running engine encounters `xdescribe` or `xit` it just don't execute them. Just put the **x** character in front of tests (or sets of tests) to be skipped.

Comment: got it but, if I have 30 E2E test in 4 different .js files I need to traverse the whole 4 .js files and the 30 test and put x in front it or describe.

Comment: Well, you can exclude unnecessary *.js files in test config. And wrap the rest e2e-tests with additional **xdescribe**.

Comment: You've said that "I noticed that the test is run is the test that the cursor is on" but editing with Sublime Text and with the cursor on top of the test I want to run doesn't seem to work. There are any other way to run a single unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To isolate a test you can use a simple trick - add "d" to describe, or i to "it".

For example:

```
describe("Should not run", function(){
  ...
});

ddescribe("Should run...", function(){
  ...
});
```

The same goes for:

```
describe("Will run", function(){
   it("should not run...", function(){

   });

   iit("should run...", function(){

   });
});
```

If you have multiple "ddescribe" or "iit" they will all run and the other regular "describe" or "it" won't.

Hope it helps...

Comment: but how did you find about it ? are you a testacular developer ?

Comment: Nope, It's a trick I saw on one of the angular videos. :)
It has more to do with Jasmine than Testacular.

Comment: can you please post the video ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation on using Testacular at the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). The test sample is specifically at [Chapter 2](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02).

Also, take a look at the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I read the tutorial but, they do not explain how to run a single e2e test :)